# Tuleap unable to upload file

Tags: centos, tuleap

I have installed tuleap on centos 6.7 and having trouble to properly configure tuleap in following scenario. I have gone though the documentation and mailing list archives but didn't find the solution.

- have ubuntu server with static ip address XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX accessible from outside
- on the above server I have installed virtualbox and installed centos 6.7 + tuleap (local ip address YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY which is accessible from above ubuntu server only)

I have setup ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse on ubuntu server which works fine:

```
    ProxyPass / https://YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY/
```

All features are working fine except when I try to upload the files. I see two issues:

1. When I try to upload file in "Document", I see below messages:

   ```
   “Permissions successfully updated.
    Document successfully created.
    Error while creating initial version.”
   ```

But when I check apache error log I see that Docman_FileStorage.class.php tries to create file in the root directory i.e. something like  /testproject/3/6/36/1 and hence get permission denied error. I am checking local.inc file but wondering where I have to set base path for storing documents?

2. I see another issue while attaching file to wiki pages. When I hit “Upload” button, the  url mysite.domain.com get transferred to YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY ip address! BUT as the YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY is virtual machine ip address and not accessible from outside, I get page not found error. Could you tell me what might be missing? My proxy-pass apache setting looks like:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName mysite.domain.com
      ServerAlias *.mysite.domain.com
      ProxyRequests off
      ProxyPreserveHost off
      SSLProxyEngine On
      SSLProxyVerify none 

      <Proxy *>
          Order deny,allow
          Allow from all
      </Proxy>

      ProxyPass / https://YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY/
      ProxyPassReverse / https://YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY/

   </VirtualHost>

   # Listen 443

   <VirtualHost mysite.domain.com:443>
      ServerName mysite.domain.com

      <Proxy *>
          Order deny,allow
          Allow from all
      </Proxy>

      SSLEngine On
      SSLProxyVerify none 
      SSLProxyEngine On
      SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/my.crt
      SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/my.key

      ProxyRequests off
      ProxyPreserveHost off
      ProxyPass / https://YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY/
      ProxyPassReverse / https://YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY/
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

Any help to solve above issues will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to look at selinux first.

Please try to run `setenforce 0` on the centos box and try to create documents again. If that solve the problem, set selinux to permissive.